# javascript: can I do the equivalent of call but for a property?

Tags: javascript

I understand that call allows you to pass in an object in place of the 'this' that the method was invoked upon.

```
"abc".charAt.call("defgh",1);
"e"
```

But suppose I want the length property to be applied to that object

I can't say

```
"abc".length.call("defgh");
```

i'll get an error

Can I do it for a property e.g. length?

**Added** [since this addition, the 3 answers I see to this question are all good]

It appears some people have thought I was questioning how to invoke a property (which makes no sense). I am not.

And some have thought that I was suggesting that "z".charAt("asdf",0)  is better than `"asdf".chatAt(0)`  I am not.

What I am saying is that you can use call on a method to cause it to execute/evaluate on a different object.  I could give a more useful example if you really need  to see a more useful example.

`[1].forEach.call("asdf",function(x){console.log(x+x);});`

or

`Array.prototype.forEach.call("asdf",function(x){console.log(x+x);});`

So forEach can be more concise than a For loop.

So there, even though initially the example I gave for call was not useful, lo and behold, a useful example can exist.

So too, that may be the case with a property

I may want to apply a different object, for a property e.g. 'length' to evaluate on. That should not be impossible in theory(as one answerer suggested before deleting his answer).  I don't have a particular use I can come up with that would be beneficial for evaluating a property on a different object, but it should not be impossible.

And just because I don't have a use for it, doesn't mean it should be thrown away. Remember that prior to giving a good usage for call on a method, some said it's pointless, then I gave potentially be a use for it. And that's no argument for it being impossible in theory/principle.

Comment: `call` and `apply` are methods on [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). The `length` property is not a function

Comment: You can only invoke on a `method` and not a `property`

Comment: I am aware of that. That's why i'm asking how I can pass the object to seen by length

Comment: @barlop what is the point? What's wrong with `'defgh'.length`?

Comment: @zerkms  You can say what is the point of `"abc".charAt.call("defgh",1);` but you can do it

Comment: @barlop I cannot say what is the point for it. It's a stupid code.

Comment: @zerkms well then your argument is wrong isn't it. You said what's the point of the second example, as if it's some kind of reason why it can't be done.  Well, you don't know the point of the first example either, but the first one can be done

Comment: It's not. What is the point to do that? Why not `'defgh'.charAt(1)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86653/discussion-between-barlop-and-zerkms).

Comment: "That should not be impossible in theory(as one answerer suggested before deleting his answer)." --- well, prove it. I asked that 5 times already. In theory it's as stupid as in practice. No one should ever want that.

Comment: "Remember that prior to giving a good usage for call on a method, some said it's pointless" --- I still say so. It's silly to create an object just to throw it away, there is a `prototype` for that.

Comment: @zerkms please add any further comments you have  to the chat link already generated, that's what it's for

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent way to take the functionality behind the `.length` property and apply it to a different object.  Javascript does not have that feature.

Part of the reason is because a property can be just a static value stuck in a property on an object, so there's meaning to evaluate the `"ttt".length` property on another object.  You can access the `.length` property on another object, but there's no semantic meaning to using the `"ttt"` object's `.length` property on another object.  The only semantic thing you have is a name.  You can use that name on another object as in `obj2["length"]` or `obj2.length`, but all you've borrowed from the `"ttt"` object is the name of the property.  It's different with functions that are methods on objects.  They are executable code that is passed a `this` value as context.  `.call()` allows you to take any function (whether a method or not) and specify the value of `this` when it is executed by using `.call()`.  That's why you can take a method on one object and call it in the context of another object.  But, a plain (non-function) property just doesn't have that capability.  There's nothing to "execute" in a different context.  The property just has a name and a value.  You can use the name on any other object, but there's no code you can execute in a different context for that property.

Also, keep in mind once you've retrieved `"ttt".length`, all you have at that point is a number.  That number has no context about where it came from so there isn't really any way to apply the logic that generated that number to some other object.

---

As for `.call()`, it is a method of a `Function` object.  So, you can only use it with functions.  That's why it works fine with the `.charAt()` method because that's a function.

But the `.length` property is not a function (it returns a number) so it does not have a `.call()` method.  That's why what you're trying does not work.

Because `.length` is not a function, you cannot take the functionality behind it and arbitrarily apply it to another object the way you tried to do with `.charAt()`.  That simply isn't supported with non-functions.

You can, of course, just use the `.length` property that is already on your other string as in:

```
console.log("defgh".length);
```

If you can describe what you're really trying to accomplish, we can probably offer a different way to do it that is supported, but your current description of what you're trying to do does not really seem logical so it's hard to figure out what the actual problem is you're trying to solve.

---

FYI, there's really no reason to have done this either:

```
"abc".charAt.call("defgh",1);
```

You might as well just do the much more direct scheme of calling a method on the desired object:

```
"defgh".charAt(1);   // "e"
```

Comment: The example I gave wasn't intended to be one that is really useful, just to demonstrate a principle.. I'm well aware that  `"asdf".chatAt(0)` is simpler than `"z".charAt.call("asdf",0)`  It's not like I was trying to find out how to find the first character of "asdf" and I did that example with the call. So maybe if you thought that then you misunderstood what I was asking

Comment: @barlop - you will generally get more meaningful answers if you share the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than a made-up example.  Besides, giving us the opportunity to see and understand the actual problem you have and offer you solutions you might not have even thought of, it also prevents the criticism of a made-up, not really particularly useful example.  This site always works better with a description of a real problem instead of a hypothetical example.

Comment: there, i've added to the question

Comment: and if you want to question there is a chat link in the comments to the question

Comment: Also, before you posted your answer, if you'd check my comments, I said I said in response to sombebody, that I am well aware that you can't invoke a property.

Comment: @barlop - All I did is explain what you can do with `.call()` and why you can't do what you were trying to do. I'm not sure what beef you have with my answer.  It remains true that `.call()` ONLY applies to functions and `.length` is not a function so you cannot use `.call()` with `.length`.  Furthermore, you cannot use the functionality behind `.length` with a different object.  You just can't.

Comment: Well, I think my comment to you that you should've checked the comments before answering, is valid because you begun by telling me things that I already said I was aware of. And furthermore re your recent comment, I am aware of why it's not working and hence I asked if there was an *equivalent* way - right there in my title.

Comment: @barlop - The answer is "No".  There is no equivalent way to use the functionality behind `.length` on a different object.  That is not a capability that Javascript has.

Comment: You write " There is no equivalent way to use the functionality behind .length on a different object." <--- There is no functionality behind length, length is not a function you know that, and I know that.   Now, it may be that there's no equivalent way to get length to apply to another object. But you could simply say that rather than tell me things i'm aware of for the bulk of your post, which you'd have known if you'd checked the comments

Comment: @barlop - wow.  You're awfully argumentative.  I've answered your question precisely and you're still arguing.  Actually it is YOUR responsibility to put all relevant information into your question and not expect people to read all possible comments in order to understand your question.  For most of the lifetime of your question, it was NOT clear.  Still, I tried to be helpful and answer what I thought you were asking.  Perhaps that was a mistake in this case given how unappreciative you are of someone who just tried to help.

Comment: @barlop - Is there any remaining issue in your question that is not answered yet?

Comment: The first paragraph/2 sentences of your answer, answer my question. The rest is not relevant and is just based on a misunderstanding of my question from you not reading my comments.   Your answer (the first paragraph), is an answer, though it doesn't  give a reason.  zerkms's answer beats yours somewhat as he gives a reason, though my knowledge isn't at a level whereby I can evaluate the reason he gives.

Comment: @barlop - OK, I beefed up my second paragraph.

Comment: ok thanks, it's (just your first paragraph and your beefed up second/third paragraph) is a good answer thanks.. i'll ponder it and the others.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically impossible in JS since after the `"abc".length` expression is evaluated the property name is lost (and only the value is carried over next), hence you cannot re-apply it to the another context.

So even if you extended the primitive type wrapper prototypes - you still would not be able to extract something more but the value.

So it just does not fit into the current language specification.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to evaluate the reason you give, but the nature of your answer makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of *call* and *apply* is to set the *this* object within a function call. They are necessary for calling functions as methods of objects that don't have that method. However, the caveat is that the object supplied as *this* can be used by the function.

Applying that principle to properties means trying to read a property of an object that doesn't have it, using the algorithm from some other object that does.

If you consider the *length* property that many objects have, the algorithm for determining it is very different for each type of object:

1. String: number of characters
2. Number: undefined
3. Function (built–in): as defined in ECMA-262
4. Function (native, not built–in): number of arguments
5. Array: whatever has been set, but always at least 1 greater than highest index if there is one

and so on. So which should be the generic version returned of there was an equivalent of call for properties? So There is a very large matrix of property algorithms and objects to apply them to.

However don't despair! If you wish to use, say, the String version of *length* for some object, then convert it to a string and get its length. E.g. the string version of length for an array might be:

```
someArray.join('').length;
```

So you can define the algorithm for such properties any way you like. ;-)

PS. [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) allow you to do this on a per object basis, but they can't be shared.

Comment: By `Array.join('').length;` do you mean like `Array.prototype.join.call("asdf",'').length`

Comment: I meant *Array* to be any array, not the built–in Array constructor, I'll change that…

Comment: I see you can also do `"asdf".slice.call("zz",0).length`   or `String.prototype.slice.call("zz",0).length`

Comment: Yes, so you convert the object to the required type using whatever conversion you like, then read the property. Still wondering "why" though. ;-)

Comment: As to why, here's a theoretical answer. First consider the example with call and the forEach function(I give the example in my question). It enables forEach from the array object, to be used on a string.  So if there were ever a case where an object lacked an attribute that some other object had, and the algorithm were basically the same/equivalent, then or I wanted the algorithm from the other object, then I could do that.  As for in practice, I only have an example for the function scenario, not the property scenario.

Comment: You write "Applying that principle to properties means trying to read a property of an object that doesn't have it, using the algorithm from some other object that does." <-- I guess it's more like trying to "cast"/fit an object into another 'type' so that it has the property. Which is not that different to the hack with forEach and string, which "casts"/fits string into being an array, (or the 'this' of an array object), and then it gets the new function.